# Prove that a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I need some help with this problem, I've seen that there is a similar problem about proving that Euclidean Space is a complete metric space, but I haven't learn about Euclidean or metric spaces and its notation, so the answer in that question isn't helping me.

> A sequence $(a_k)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Cauchy sequence if to each $\varepsilon>0$ there corresponds $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\Vert a_k-a_l\Vert<\varepsilon$$ whenever $k,l>K$. 
>   Prove that a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convergent. Hint apply the ideas in the proof of Theorem [2.2.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDs5K.png) and [1.6.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTgA6.png)

Ok, so I tried to do it like this:

From the theorem 2.2.7, we know that if $(a_k)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$  it converges $a_k\rightarrow a \iff a_{ki}\rightarrow a_i, \ \forall i=1,...,n.$ And $(a_l)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$  it converges $a_l\rightarrow a\iff a_{li}\rightarrow a_i, \ \forall i=1,...,n \ $, where $a_k=(a_{k1},...,a_{kn})\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$, $a=(a_1,...,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a_l=(a_{l1},...,a_{ln})\forall l\in\mathbb{N}$, $

We know that if the sequence $(a_k)$ converges, then $\forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists \ K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k>K$ $$\Vert a_k-a\Vert<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and $\exists l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $l>K$ $$\Vert a_l-a\Vert<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ $\Rightarrow \Vert a_k-a_l\Vert=\Vert a_k-a_l-a+a\Vert \leq\Vert a_k-a\Vert + \Vert a-a_l\Vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$

Thus $\Vert a_k-a_l\Vert<\varepsilon$.

Is my proof correct or not? In case not, how can I prove this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: @TheoBendit It seems similar, but I haven't learn about Euclidean or metric spaces and its notation, so the answer in that question isn't helping me.

Comment: Admittedly, the notation is attrocious. You don't need to know too much about metric spaces. The Euclidean metric is just $d(a_k, a_l) = \|a_k - a_l\|$, but you don't even need that. Try concentrating on the accepted answer; does that help?

Comment: Kind of. If I understand the answer correctly, my proof is correct, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely on the right track. I feel that your notation could be improved too (or at least explained further). I get from context that $a_{ki}$ is the $i$th entry in the vector $a_k$, but this should be explained. Also, you are missing the converse, which is widely considered to be the less trivial direction.

Comment: How can I explain it further? Should I say that both $a_{ki}$ and $a_{li}$ are Cauchy sequences? The converse is that every converget sequence is a Cauchy sequence, right?

Comment: I just mean to write essentially what I wrote in the comment, so that people don't think that $a_{ki}$ refers to the $(k \times i)$th vector in the sequence. You've assumed $a_k$ converges, and shown it's Cauchy. The converse is to assume $a_k$ is Cauchy, and construct the limit.